# CSS display li in special format

Tags: css

If I have an Ul  that contains

```
          <UL class="level2">
  <li> 
     <a>Link1</a>  
  </li>
  <li> 
   <a> Link2</a> 
 </li>
  <li> 
  <a> Link 3</a> 
 </li>

  <li class="hasChildren">
     <a>Navigation</a>
     <ul>
        <li>Navigation 1 </li>
         <li>Navigation 2</li>
         <li>Navigation 3 </li>
         <li>Navigation 4</li>
         <li>Navigation 5</li>
     </ul>
 </li>
```

I need to display the li that don't have children in block and I need the li that haschildren to be displayed inline next to it not under it any idea

I need to have :

```
         Link1      Navigation
         Link2        Navigation1    Navigation4
         Link3        Navigation2    Navigation5
                      Navigation3
```

Comment: Could you please clarify how you want the menu (I presume a menu?) to appear with some sort of textual diagram?

Comment: I need to have like the example above all the simple links on the left side and the links with children on the left side .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like [this](http://www.webdevout.net/test?01N)?

CSS:

```
ul {
    width:  600px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    display:  block;
    width: 300px;
    background: Red;

}
li.hasChildren {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background:  Green;     
}
li.hasChildren ul {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li.hasChildren ul li {
    background:  Green; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item #1</li>
    <li>Item #2</li>
    <li class="hasChildren">
        Item #3
        <ul>
            <li>Sub-item #1</li>
            <li>Sub-item #2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item #4</li>
    <li>Item #5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: if Item 3 has sub children I need it to be alone on the top right side did u know what I mean ? like i've edited the example

Comment: Here you are. Check the updated link to the example and the code in the answer, @sally

Comment: Good that it's helpful, @sally

Comment: just one more thing I need to display the sub Items Like I've Edited the form may please tell me how ?

Comment: It's not clear from the example you give what happens there, whether the items start floating to the next column after 3rd, or you try to split them even, but I suppose it smells like you want to try CSS3 columns — http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html. If you need help with this, add another question. The current one is fulfilled.

Comment: Isn't it possible in CSS to  have the form that I want I fixed the width and give the sub of Li a float: left but it's not working

Comment: just wanna nknow if it's possibble to do it in CSS /